# Filter a model before you create an resource Collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-resource

I am looking for a way that my *ProductResource* Collection will only include products with active prices.

In my `routes/api.php` am using a *Collection* as so:

```
Route::get('/product', function (Request $request) {
  return new ProductCollection(
    Product::all()
  );
});
```

In the model `App\Models\Product` there is a relationship for prices

```
public function prices () {
  return $this->hasMany(ProductsPrice::class);
}
```

and in the `App\Models\ProductsPrice` there is a scopeIsActive that I want to call before my collection is created.

```
public function scopeIsActive($query)
{
  return $query->where('is_active', true);
}
```

Is there a way I can call this *isActive* scope without creating a *Controller* just to query the Products with a active price and put that in a *ResourceCollection* in the `routes/api.php`, like so?

```
Route::get('/product', function (Request $request) {
  return new ProductCollection(
    Product::all()->prices()->isActive()
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
Route::get('/product', function (Request $request) {
  return new ProductCollection(
    Product::with(['prices' => function($query) {
        $query->isActive();
    }])->get()
  );
});
```

Comment: Thx men, didn't see this with() before, will start reading up on it. When I implemented it I'll vote you up. Thank you again!

Comment: @St.Jan okay le me know if any